# Google maps or some custom maps in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-maps

i'm trying to build an app to put addresses in certain locations of the map so users can search for it and it will pinpoint exact location in the map. Do you need AI or some technology/library for this to work with react-native.

Comment: You need this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You don't need AI technology to work. You can get the current location with this code with the required npm installation. but you need to activate google developer account and enable the developer account and enable the required API for map, then the copy the API key and paste it to you app.json like below:

```
 "android": {
      "package": <Project package name>,
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "<YOUR API KEY>"
        }
      }
    }
```

and then try this code, I have used expo here!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';

const CurrentLocation = (props) =>{
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [latLong, setLatLong] = useState(null)
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
          }
    
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setLocation(location);
            setLatLong({
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0121
            })
        })();
      });
    
      let text = 'Waiting..';
      if (errorMsg) {
        text = errorMsg;
      } else if (location) {
        text = JSON.stringify(location);
      }
      let userLocationMarker = null;

      if(latLong){
         userLocationMarker = <MapView.Marker 
                                coordinate={latLong}/>;
    }

    
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{text}</Text>
            <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
                initialRegion={{
                            latitude: 37.78825,
                            longitude: -122.4324,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
                        }}
                region={latLong}>
               {userLocationMarker}
           </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}

export default CurrentLocation;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    mapStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      },
  });
```